# VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” when insert code for find empty column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still learning for make simple VBA excel. I am having an issue with a Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when trying to input code as below. Can anyone help me or suggest the right code to fix this issue?

Thank you very much, I hope someone can help me

```
Dim iColumn As Long
Dim WtrData As Worksheets
Set Wsh = Worksheets("WtrData")
iColumn = Wsh.Cells(0, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Column `**Yellow mark at here when Debug**`

Wsh.Cells(-58, iColumn).Value = Me.Intake.Value
Wsh.Cells(-56, iColumn).Value = Me.ServisOut.Value
Wsh.Cells(-54, iColumn).Value = Me.ProsesOut.Value
Wsh.Cells(-52, iColumn).Value = Me.Regenerasi.Value
Wsh.Cells(-50, iColumn).Value = Me.ServisTank.Value
Wsh.Cells(-48, iColumn).Value = Me.Brewhouse.Value
Wsh.Cells(-46, iColumn).Value = Me.Wetmill.Value
Wsh.Cells(-44, iColumn).Value = Me.Filtration.Value
Wsh.Cells(-42, iColumn).Value = Me.Filtrox.Value
Wsh.Cells(-40, iColumn).Value = Me.TankFarm.Value
Wsh.Cells(-38, iColumn).Value = Me.CIP.Value
Wsh.Cells(-36, iColumn).Value = Me.Yeast.Value
Wsh.Cells(-34, iColumn).Value = Me.Boiler.Value
Wsh.Cells(-32, iColumn).Value = Me.AC.Value
Wsh.Cells(-30, iColumn).Value = Me.CO.Value
Wsh.Cells(-28, iColumn).Value = Me.Mycom.Value
Wsh.Cells(-26, iColumn).Value = Me.Packaging.Value
Wsh.Cells(-24, iColumn).Value = Me.Lab.Value
Wsh.Cells(-21, iColumn).Value = Me.WWTPToilet.Value
Wsh.Cells(-18, iColumn).Value = Me.AdmBuilding.Value
Wsh.Cells(-15, iColumn).Value = Me.Amenities.Value
Wsh.Cells(-12, iColumn).Value = Me.Masjid.Value
Wsh.Cells(-6, iColumn).Value = Me.Hydrant.Value
Wsh.Cells(-3, iColumn).Value = Me.Garden.Value

Call MsgBox("Data Berhasil Disimpan", vbInformation, "Input Data")
```

Comment: `iColumn = Wsh.Cells(0`.... there's no row `0`. Additionally, there are no cells with a negative row number, so anything like `Wsh.Cells(-58` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still error :( I have the picture of my excel format down below. Maybe you can help me to find the right code, really appreciate with that @BigBen

Comment: I'm so sorry @BigBen still confuse using stack overflow. This is my excel format https://i.stack.imgur.com/la46l.png If I want to input data in white cells, any suggestion what code I can use? Thank you

Comment: You can start by finding the last column correctly as demonstrated in the posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the first empty column in row 6 you should be using something like this.

```vb
lColumn = wsh.Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
```